# Add NSLayoutContraint between UITableViewCell and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

So, I want to add a constraint that enforce a maximum height on every cell to be smaller than or equal to 2/3 of the `UITableView`'s height.

How can I achieve this?

Adding the constraint in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` is not an option, since the cell is not in the `UITableView`, so it complains that they have no common superview.

So basically, how do I relate my `UITableViewCell`s and my `UITableView` with `NSLayoutContraint`s?

Comment: Do you need to use a constraint here, can you not just calculate the cell heights from within heightForRowAtIndexPath? e.g. return tableView.frame.size.height * 2/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can't do it like that. What you can do is get the height of the tableview and then add a height constraint on your cells of that amount. So in interface builder add a height constraint for your cell and set it to a convenient value (just to see what is in the table, it will be updated from code). Then add a reference in code for that constraint. Then in update the value of the constraint:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellidentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell
    cell.heightConstraint.constant =  2.0 * tableview.frame.size.height / 3.0
}
```

This is if you are using dynamic size cells. Otherwise you could just override: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` and return the size you want.

Comment: Not as elegant as what I was looking for, but was a nice idea. In any case, it doesn't work, because `cell.heightContraint` is `nil` at that time.

Comment: It should not be. It is just a regular outlet. It should work the same way a label or a view outlet works. Make sure you use the right cell and that your constrain is active. If you deactivate it will be deallocated if you do not specify it as `strong`.

Comment: that doesn't make sense, why would it get deallocated when setting active to false?

Comment: Because it is actually removed from the layout when you set `.active = false` so there is no strong reference to it anymore.

Comment: I'll try that. What a bad design from Apple... In any case, I did manage to keep the constraint in another way, and it does fix this problem, but when I set active to false, it breaks other cells, as if the constraint was not deactivated.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but you cannot simply change the height of the cells after they are displayed. You must also refresh the tableview.